# \sections without numbers, but in ToC and in running heads

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, header-footer

I'm doing a book-class doc which is a collection of problems offered through some years.

So each chapter is a year, and it always has two sections: Problems, and Solutions. And I need them to NOT be numbered, BUT added to ToC (without number), and be present in the running head on the odd page.

`secnumdepth` doesn't do it, because subsections (the problems) *are* numbered

I've tried using `\renewcommand{\thesection}{}` but this only makes the numbers disappear, while the space that was between the section number and the header is preserved, so the section titles appear off in the ToC. The same space is present in the running head, and additionally, a full stop appears before the space in the running head.

I've also tried

```
\newcommand\problems{\section*{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Problems}Problems}
```

which makes for an ok-looking ToC, but doesn't give me the running heads.

I understand that packages like `titlesec` and `titletoc` might help me, but I'd rather make it as standalone-ish as possible.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) have you tried `\markboth`?

Comment: Which document class do you use? If you use `scrbook` you can use `\addchap`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel, I use `\documentclass{book}`. @cmhughes, you did it! `\markright` with `\addcontentsline` inserted into `\section*` does the trick! I somehow got the impression that only fancyhdr could change the running heads, totally forgot about the mark commands.

Comment: ok, that's great :) - I'll flag it for a moderator as we have resolved it in the comments. Note that you can only 'ping' one person per message using the `@` symbol :)

Comment: @cmhughes Below I proposed a solution that doesn't require any manual intervention and that might be useful for the OP, so I would like to ask you not to flag the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use manually issue `\markright` and `\addcontentsline` commands after each section. Let LaTeX do all the work for you: redefine `\thesection` (and `\thesubsection`) appropriately; for example:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
```

redefine `\l@section` to suppress the indentation for entries in the ToC; redefine `\section` to suppress the indent in the titles, and finally (re)define `\sectionmark` to give you the desired header:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\thesection{}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{1.5em}}
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{-1em}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\def\sectionmark#1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{2012}
\section{Problems}
\subsection{First problem}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```